# Instalar o APCu no PHP 7.1

Tags: php

Gostaria de instalar o APCu no PHP 7.1 pelo windows. Estou instalando uma aplicação e rodando direto na minha máquina pelo XAMPP, porém quando chega na hora da instalação mostra o a mensagem: A extensão apcu-bc não está presente.

Alguém sabe como instalar essa extensão no PHP 7.1 ?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baixe o arquivo `php_apcu.dll` aqui: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apcu/

Baixe o arquivo `php_apcu_bc.dll` aqui: https://pecl.php.net/package/apcu_bc

Depois copie os arquivos `php_apcu.dll` e `php_apcu_bc.dll` para a pasta `ext` na pasta de instalação do PHP.

Abra o arquivo `php.ini` e encontre as seguintes linhas e remova os comentário, ou se não houver adicione-as:

```
extension=php_apcu.dll
extension=php_apcu_bc.dll
```

Depois acrescente as seguintes linhas de configuração também no `php.ini`:

```
[APCu]
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=32M
apc.ttl=7200
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.serializer=php
```

Reinicie o servidor e teste novamente.